# How can i set my year picker to read the maximum year as the current year

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to configure this code to read the current year as the maximum selectable year and I have failed. Also when I select the first year, I don't want the second year to be less than the first one. Can any one help me please?

Here is the code.

```
 $('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
        $(this).datepicker({
            minViewMode: 2,
            format: 'yyyy'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: "read the maximum year as the current year". You mean set the current year to be the maximum selectable? And which plugin is it? Also, there seems to be no need to re-initialise the datepicker every time the control gains focus. You can just write `$(".datepicker").datepicker({...etc` once, outside the "focus" event handler. Unless you set it to, the picker won't actually appear until the control has focus. Right now you're destroying and re-creating the picker each time the user focuses on the control, which is wasteful, plus you may lose any existing data.

Comment: Which datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: yes.set the current year to be the maximum selecctable

Comment: we need to know which of the many datepickers available you are actually using. Otherwise we can't help. They all have different options and APIs. Is it the bootstrap one?

Comment: Also "i don't want the second year to be less than the first one". Where is the second year chosen? In another datepicker?? It is possible to use a single control to select a date range, if you set it up properly. But you haven't explained your situation properly.

Comment: Years am actually using another datepicker to record the second year

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date` class to get current date, then use it:

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
   $(this).datepicker({
     minViewMode: 2,
     endDate: new Date(),
     format: 'yyyy'
   });
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that help.

Comment: i just want to ask you another question.if am taking the year range,how can i set the second year that is entered to be greater than the first year entered using the year picker above.thanks